StyleSheet global reference in vscode refers to a browser type file
In my react-native project, references to StyleSheet are by default referring to a global dom type. These dom types aren't actually relevant to my react-native project, and makes it so I can't use my eslint fix option to import the StyleSheet class from react-native (I have to just manually write the import statement). Does anyone know how I can disable this? When I click through the global type in vscode, it takes me to
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts
If possible, I'd like to disable all of these global dom types. (the same thing happens when i refer to Text, for example). I imagine there's some configuration option that I have accidentally enabled, so if someone could point me in the right direction to remove this that would be much appreciated!

You can exclude using these global DOM types by specifying the "lib" property in your tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json as follows:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2022"]
  }
}

This example uses ES2022 as the target and library to include.
The library you don't want would be DOM, you can find a list of all libraries and components you can pass to lib here.
